# Connecting HTML to existing Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have installed Laravel script which has his own front page (homepage) which i dont like and wanted to replace with my own html. I moved css, images to public folder, renames index.html to index.blade.php (moved to resources/views) and added routing - *Route::get('/index2', function () {return view('index2');});* but it does not load my homepage. I changed all links to css inside my home.blade.php like this -  /assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"> .

1. There is an existing routing -*Route::get('/','HomeController@index');* which loads old homepage. Do i remove it or leave it be?
2. And why it's named different - homecontroller@index?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hello Mark S can you pls attach a screenshot of your folder structure and also the code snippet of your blade files, route, and controller as this will enable us to guide you. Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove the default Route from **web.php** and Add below code

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index'); //Change blade as per your file name
})->name('home');
```

`homecontroller@index` This is the default controller and `index` method which you get. Basically in index method returns the default welcome page blade. You can use that as well if you want.

1. Divide your HTML code into Separate small components. So you can extend the same code in different files.
2. Use a named route instead of a direct URL in `<a href="route('home')"></a>` like this.

Comment: HI Apurv. Thank you for reply and suggestion. I tried to add:  " Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index'); 
})->index('home'); " but it did not work. Also, what do you mean under point 2? Is this for index.blade.php to link to css?

Comment: Can you show what you get after changing it.

Comment: You need to understand the laravel routing for 2nd point. how it can helpful to you